# React Native LIstItem component TouchableHighlight onPress not working

Tags: react-native

I have the following React Native `ListItem` and the onPress is not logging to the console:

```
    <ListItem
        rightIcon={{name: 'delete', style: {color: 'white'}}}
        component={TouchableHighlight}
        containerStyle={styles[item.foodType]}
        title={<Text style={styles[item.foodType]}>{item.amount}&nbsp;{item.foodType}&nbsp;<FormattedDateTime epoch={item.when}/></Text>}>
        onPress={() => console.log("Feeding", item) }
    </ListItem>
```

Everything else works fine, list looks good, etc...

Why do I not see the message?

Comment: We're gonna need to see the source code of the `ListItem` component to be able to help you.

Comment: it's react-native-elements https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/lists/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the closing tag of ListItem before onpress which is wrong, just change it to after onpress like this.

Before

```
<ListItem
    rightIcon={{name: 'delete', style: {color: 'white'}}}
    component={TouchableHighlight}
    containerStyle={styles[item.foodType]}
    title={<Text style={styles[item.foodType]}>{item.amount}&nbsp;{item.foodType}&nbsp;<FormattedDateTime epoch={item.when}/></Text>}>
    onPress={() => console.log("Feeding", item) }
</ListItem>
```

After

```
<ListItem
    rightIcon={{name: 'delete', style: {color: 'white'}}}
    component={TouchableHighlight}
    containerStyle={styles[item.foodType]}
    title={<Text style={styles[item.foodType]}>{item.amount}&nbsp;{item.foodType}&nbsp;<FormattedDateTime epoch={item.when}/></Text>}
    onPress={() => console.log("Feeding", item) }>
</ListItem>
```

Or like this

```
<ListItem
    rightIcon={{name: 'delete', style: {color: 'white'}}}
    component={TouchableHighlight}
    containerStyle={styles[item.foodType]}
    title={<Text style={styles[item.foodType]}>{item.amount}&nbsp;{item.foodType}&nbsp;<FormattedDateTime epoch={item.when}/></Text>}
    onPress={() => console.log("Feeding", item) }/>
```